# Plotting overlaying time series

Tags: r, plot, time-series, radix

I have four time series which I want to plot, preferably using base graphics.

```
year<-c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007) #x axis
a<-c(36.2,42.4,43.4,56.4,67.4,42.4,22.4,20.4) 
b<-c(NA,NA,NA,56.4,67.4,42.4,22.4,20.4) 
c<-c(36.4,42.3,43.7,56.4,67.2,88.3,99.3,99.9) 
d<-c(36.4,42.3,43.7,56.4,NA,NA,NA,NA) 

#using different thickness of lines to distinguish between them? Dunno
par(mar = c(4,4,4,4))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(year,a, xlab="Year", ylab="Whatever", type="l", lwd=6, ylim=c(20, 100))
lines(year,b, type="l", lwd=2, col="yellow")
plot(year,c, xlab="Year", ylab="Whatever", type="l", lwd=6, ylim=c(20, 100))
lines(year,d, type="l", lwd=2, col="yellow")
```

As you can see, one out of two series is always a subset of the other one and the series a and b are quite similar in their beginning so it would not look good in one plot (of this characteristics).
Do you have any suggestion how to plot this kind of data? I wouldn't mind having it all in one plot, but it is not necessary. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses plot.zoo which in turn uses base graphics and accepts most of the base graphics graphical parameters.  Note that in `plot.zoo` that `col` and `lwd` are recycled.  The `screen` argument indicates which each series is in so to put it all in one panel replace the `screen` argument with `screen = 1`.  Add `main` and other arguments as desired.  See `?plot.zoo` and first plot below.

```
library(zoo)
plot(zoo(cbind(a, b, c, d), year), screen = c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
  col = c("black", "yellow"), ylim = c(20, 100), lwd = c(6, 2))
```

Also note that in this case by adding just `library(lattice)` and changing `plot` to `xyplot` we can get a lattice plot via `xyplot.zoo` (second plot below).

[image: plot.zoo plot]

[image: xyplot.zoo plot]

Comment: Is there any way how to put them next to each other? I tried `rbind` instead of `cbind`, which didn't work.

Comment: @Vochmeika, The `plot.zoo` argument `nc=2` would plot the panels in two columns rather than in one column.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
year <- c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007) #x axis
a <- c(36.2,42.4,43.4,56.4,67.4,42.4,22.4,20.4) 
b <- c(NA,NA,NA,56.4,67.4,42.4,22.4,20.4) 
c <- c(36.4,42.3,43.7,56.4,67.2,88.3,99.3,99.9) - 100
d <- c(36.4,42.3,43.7,56.4,NA,NA,NA,NA) - 100

#using different thickness of lines to distinguish between them? Dunno
par(mar = c(4,4,4,4))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(year,a, xlab="Year", ylab="Whatever", type="l", lwd=6, ylim=c(-100, 100))
lines(year,b, type="l", lwd=2, col="yellow")
lines(year,c, xlab="Year", ylab="Whatever", type="l", lwd=6, ylim=c(-100, 100))
lines(year,d, type="l", lwd=2, col="yellow")
```